# Comment expansion oddity

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments

I [recently wanted to see if the comment lengths applied to the comment pre- or post-expansion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/117561/157556) (it applies pre-expansion). I found though that my input `[so][so][so]...[so]` expanded oddly:

> Stack OverflowStack OverflowStack OverflowStack OverflowStack
>   OverflowStack OverflowStack OverflowStack OverflowStack OverflowStack
>   OverflowStack OverflowStack OverflowStack OverflowStack OverflowStack
>   OverflowStack OverflowStack OverflowStack OverflowStack OverflowStack
>   Overflow[‌​so]Stack OverflowStack OverflowStack OverflowStack
>   OverflowStack ...

The odd portion is the `[so]` that remains in the comment text; if I paste this content into `vim`, the `[so]` portions are downright strange:

```
[<200c><200b>so]
[s<200c><200b>o]
[<200c><200b>so]
[s<200c><200b>o]
[<200c><200b>so]
[s<200c><200b>o]
[<200c><200b>so]
```

This feels like a bug, but I can't imagine that fixing it is a priority for anyone, certainly not myself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those symbols are 'ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER' (U+200C) and 'ZERO WIDTH SPACE' (U+200B).

I'm sure they are added on purpose, to break long lines. They are added after 81 or 82 characters if there is no whitespace. This is also the amount of characters used in your pre-expansion `[so][so][so]...[so]` code until the first occurrence of those characters.

Insertion of those characters after doing expansions would probably fix this. Not sure if fixing this would be worth the time, as a comment containing such long sequences of tags is probably nonsense or spam anyway.